# Write into cloud sql using dataflow JdbcIO api

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-sql

I have a requirement where i have to write a [PCollection](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/) of String to a Cloud SQL using Cloud Dataflow API.

```
pipeline.apply(TextIO.read().from("gs://***/sampleBigtable.csv"))
    .apply(JdbcIO.write()
    .withDataSourceConfiguration(DataSourceConfiguration
    .create("org.postgresql.Driver", "jdbc:postgresql://***:5432/test")
    .withUsername("**").withPassword("password10"))
    .withStatement("insert into person values(?,?)")
    .withPreparedStatementSetter(
 new JdbcIO.PreparedStatementSetter < Object > () {
  /**
   * 
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1 L;

  @Override
  public void setParameters(Object arg0, PreparedStatement query)
  throws Exception {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   query.setString(1, "Hello");
   query.setString(1, "Hi");
  }
 }));
```

This is the sample code I am trying. A very simple version of what I want to do.

Also, is it feasible to write into Cloud SQL from Dataflow using a parDo and writing simple insert statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The previous transform outputs a `PCollection<String>`, so you need to specify that was the input type to the `JdbcIO<T>.write()`

Something like this:

```
    pipeline
        .apply(TextIO.read().from("gs://***/sampleBigtable.csv"))
        .apply(JdbcIO.<String>write().withDataSourceConfiguration(
            DataSourceConfiguration.create("org.postgresql.Driver","jdbc:postgresql://***:5432/test")
                .withUsername("**")
                .withPassword("password10"))
                .withStatement("insert into person values(?,?)")
                    .withPreparedStatementSetter((element, query) -> {
                        query.setInt(1, 1);
                        query.setString(2, "Hello");
                    })
        );
```

Comment: Got it. Works Great. My mistake. Thank you.